# Enviar e-mail com código HTML

Tags: php, email

Boas, estou a tentar enviar um e-mail em PHP que se escreve com o CKEDITOR, ou seja HTML. Quando o e-mail é enviado o código HTML aparece no e-mail, sei que é dos Headers mas ja tentei colocar imensos e nenhum funciona.

Abaixo segue o meu código para enviar o e-mail.

```
function mail_users($titulo, $conteudo){
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `Email`, `Nome` FROM `utilizadores` WHERE `Newsletter` = 'Ativada'");
 while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) !== false){
     $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
     $header .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    email($row['Email'], $titulo, "Olá " . $row['Nome'] . ",\n\n" .  $conteudo, $header);
}
}
```

**Solução encontrada**

```
function mail_users($titulo, $conteudo){
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `Email`, `Nome` FROM `utilizadores` WHERE `Newsletter` = 'Ativada'");

$header = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$header .= "From: luismiguel@letraseletras.com\r\n";
$header .= "Return-Path: luismiguelcandeias7@gmail.com\r\n";
while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) !== false){

    mail($row['Email'], $titulo, "Ol&aacute; " . $row['Nome'] . "," .  $conteudo, $header);
}
}
```

Comment: Você tem certeza que está enviando algum HTML? Como o Content-type é HTML o e \n\n não é, creio que não seja interpretado como quebra de linha, tente substituir por <br><br>.

Comment: Luis, por favor, publique a solução como uma Resposta abaixo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Envie esse e-mail com [PHPMailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/files/phpmailer%20for%20php5_6/), é muito fácil de implementar e não falta exemplo:

```
<?php
//Site: http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/files/phpmailer%20for%20php5_6/
include "class.phpmailer.php"; //caminho do arquivo da classe do phpmailer

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP(); // send via SMTP
$mail->Host = "mail.seudominio"; //Endereço do seu Servidor de Email
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // true se o email é autenticado
$mail->Username = "usuario@seudominio"; // Seu endereço de email que envia os email
$mail->Password = "000000"; // senha do usuário que envia o email
$mail->From = "de@seudominio"; a pessoa que ta enviando o email

$mail->FromName = "remetente"; Nome de quem ta enviando...
$mail->AddAddress("email@destinatario","Nome do Destinatario ");
$mail->AddAddress("email@destinatario"); // (opcional) só o envio pelo email
$mail->AddReplyTo("email@destinatario.copia","Nome do Destinatario para quem ira a resposta");

$mail->WordWrap = 50; // Quebra de linha
$mail->IsHTML(true); // Se for true é enviando email no formato HTML
$mail->Subject = "Assunto da mensagem "; //Assunto do seu Email
$mail->Body = "Conteúdo da mensagem HTML"; //Conteudo HTML
$mail->AltBody = "Para mensagens somente texto"; //Somente Texto

//Enviando o Email e tento a confirmação se foi ou não ...
if(!$mail->Send())
{
    echo "Aconteceu algum problema no envio da Mensagem: ";
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "E-mail enviado com sucesso...";
}
```

Mais Exemplos:

- [Enviar e-mails pelo PHP usando o PHPMailer (Locaweb)](http://wiki.locaweb.com.br/pt-br/Enviar_e-mails_pelo_PHP_usando_o_PHPMailer)
- [Enviar e-mails pelo PHP usando o PHPMailer (Thiago Belem)](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/enviar-e-mails-pelo-php-usando-o-phpmailer/)
- [Enviando e-mail com o PHPMailer (Devmedia)](http://www.devmedia.com.br/enviando-e-mail-com-o-phpmailer/9642)